# What's the easiest way to mark a category as featured in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, categories, wordpress-featured-image

Is there a way to mark a category as featured, the way you can mark a whole post as featured? I'm looking for something similar to the star you can click on to make a page/post featured, but to apply that to a chosen category for an individual post.

Right now, we are using the categories to mark cities which will get a news story (Birmingham, Montgomery, Mobile, etc.). But we also want one city to double as the origin of the story. So if the story takes place in Birmingham, we'd like to "star" or feature it, and then the rest of the checked categories (cities in the area) will also see the story in their feed.

It would seem like a waste to copy the whole category/taxonomy just to save the story origin data.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: WordPress doesn't have anything like this out of the box.  Are you trying to add it with your own plugin?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, so far I have tried looking at the featured post code to see if I can repurpose it. I figured this would probably need to be coded out from scratch. I could use ACF as @JamesInglis mentioned.

Comment: I find ACF to be very heavy and try to avoid using it for small things like this.  Depending on how comfortable you are with coding, I would consider adding a custom field to the `Reading` settings page that is just populated with a list of categories.  You can read about how to do that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API#Adding_Setting_Fields)

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved something similar to this in a WooCommerce implementation, using Advanced Custom Fields (I was using the pro version but it may work with the free version) to maintain two different sets of product categories.

You already have your categories set up. You then create a custom field for the post type of the type "Taxonomy", and set it to access the list of terms from the original taxonomy (in your case, categories). You have various options to sync data between the two fields (one-way or two-way sync), but with this approach, you can maintain a single taxonomy list.